# How can I use environment variable in hibernate config file?

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am currently using database parameters in hibernate(Version 4.0.1) file through properties file.

I want to use some database parameters from environment variable. How can I fetch values from java files and set in to xml files before that loads in context.

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.jasypt.spring31.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <constructor-arg ref="configurationEncryptor" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:/test/demo/prop/DataParam.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

<bean id="data" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass">
            <value>${driverClass}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="jdbcUrl">
            <value>${dbconnecturl}</value>
        </property> 
        .
        .
        .
</beans>
```

I got some idea to make an object of Configuration class but I don't know where to write that code and how it would be implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **spring expression language** to configure the properties from OS environemnt variables as shown below:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.jasypt.spring31.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <constructor-arg ref="configurationEncryptor" />
            <property name="locations">
                <list>
                    <value>classpath:/test/demo/prop/DataParam.properties</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>

    <bean id="data" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
            <property name="driverClass">
                <value>#{ systemProperties['driverClass']}</value>
            </property>
            <property name="jdbcUrl">
                <value>#{ systemProperties['dbconnecturl']}</value>
            </property> 
            .
            .
            .
    </beans>
```

Comment: Thanks for solution.
What should I do if my JDBC URL is made of 2 environment variable and some string.
In that case what should be the syntax.How can I merge? 
will it work if I write something like this?
In my local system URL is 
connectionUrl=jdbc:edb://127.0.0.1:5432/test

<property name="jdbcUrl">
   <value>"#{ jdbc:edb://systemProperties['OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_HOST']:systemProperties['OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PORT']//test }"</value>
</property>

Comment: <value>#{ (systemProperties['dbconnecturl1']}).concat(systemProperties['dbconnecturl2']}) } </value>

Answer (score 1):

You can use as `<property name="username" value="#{systemProperties['dbUsername']}"/>` for instance.

The variable **systemProperties** is predefined, you can see [Xml Based Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef-xml-based) for more details.